# jQuery Mobile refresh collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a few `<div data-role="collapsible">...</div>`in my page (I don't use a collapsible set because I want the possibility to open several at once) and then I remove them and create a few new ones with Javascript. Now I want them to have the jQuery Mobile Styling, but whatever I do, they won't refresh. I tried:

```
$("parentdiv").refresh();
$("parentdiv").trigger("create");
$(".ui-collapsible").refresh();
$(".ui-collapsible").trigger("create");
```

I even put a collapsible-set around each one and tried to do the refresh with this (described in the [jQuery Mobile Documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-collapsible-set-methods.html))

I add the new divs with `$("<div data-role="collapsible">...</div>").insertBefore("#foo");`

What is the proper way to do it? And is the content getting displayed in jQuery Mobile style, too, after the refresh?

**UPDATE**

The content of the collapsible was not refreshed here is my code:

```
var newColla = "<div id=\"colla" + i + "\" data-role=\"collapsible\" data-collapsed=\"true\" data-collapsed-icon=\"minus\" data-expanded-icon=\"bars\">" +
               "<h3 id=\"" + matrikelnummer + "\">" + matrikelnummer + " " + studentName + "</h3><div class=\"colla-content\">" + 
               "<div data-role=\"fieldcontain\" style=\"margin:0px;width:100%;text-align:right;\">" + 
                    "<a href=\"\" data-role=\"button\" id=\"edit_" + matrikelnummer + "_" + studentName + "\" class=\"edit ui-btn-right\" data-mini=\"true\" data-inline=\"true\" data-icon=\"edit\" data-iconpos=\"left\">Teilnehmer bearbeiten</a>" +  
                    "<a href=\"\" data-role=\"button\" id=\"delete_" + matrikelnummer + "_" + studentName + "\" class=\"delete ui-btn-right\" data-mini=\"true\" data-inline=\"true\" data-icon=\"delete\" data-iconpos=\"left\">Teilnehmer löschen</a>" + 
                "</div>";
// Für jede ausgewählte Aufgabe einen Slider hinzufügen
for (var j = 0; j < aufgaben.length; j++) {
    newColla += "<label for=\"slider_mini\">Aufgabe " + aufgaben[j] + ": (max." + allMaxPoints[j] + "Pkt.)</label>" +
    "<input type=\"range\" name=\"slider_mini_" + matrikelnummer + "_" + aufgaben[j] +"\" class=\"slider-mini allSliders\" id=\"slider_mini_" + matrikelnummer + "_" + aufgaben[j] + "\" " + theme + " step= 0.5 value=\"0\"" + 
    "min=\"0.0\" max=\"" + allMaxPoints[j] + "\" data-highlight=\"true\" data-mini=\"true\" />"; 
                                }
newColla += "</div></div>";
$(newColla).collapsible().trigger("create").insertAfter("#timer");
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is to use `.collapsible()`, there is no `refresh` method for *collapsible* widget.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    var collapsible = '<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>Heading</h3><p>Contents</p></div>';
    $("[data-role=content]").append($(collapsible).collapsible());
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/AqbyA/)**

Comment: the collapsible is now shown as a jQuery Mobile collapsible. but the content (I have sliders and buttons in it) does not refresh

Comment: @elementzero23 in this case you `$(collapsible).collapsible().trigger("create")`. Which version are your using?

Comment: I am using jQuery Mobile 1.3.2
Will try this later

Comment: @elementzero23 `$(collapsible).collapsible().trigger("create")` should enhance all elements within collapsible. If not, please update OP with code.

Comment: @elementzero23 check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/AqbyA/, `.trigger("create")` should be called on parent div `$("[data-role=content]").append($(collapsible).collapsible()).trigger("create");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$( ".selector" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
```